# UITapGestureRecognizer called immediately

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a `imageview` as shown below

```
let gest=UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(imgPressed()));
gest.delegate=self
thalaImg.addGestureRecognizer(gest)
```

And here is the `imgPressed` function :

```
func imgPressed()
{ 
    let alert=UIAlertController(title: "Img", message: "img pressed", preferredStyle: .Alert) 
    let okButton=UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil) 
    alert.addAction(okButton) 
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

I added the 3 lines of code in `viewdidload`, added a breakpoint and ran the application.What i observed is that once the compiler comes to the first line i.e let gest..., it is calling the action method immediately even before the application starts running.Since obviously the `window` is yet to load, it throws the below warning

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I don't understand why this is happening .Can someone please help me with this issue?

Thank you

Comment: 'func imgPressed()
    {
        let alert=UIAlertController(title: "Img", message: "img pressed", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        
        let okButton=UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }'

Comment: Okay remove () after imgPressed method.And in double quote "imgPressed".

Comment: Are you working on which swift version means swift 2.0 or swift 3.0?

Comment: You have bound the method to the gesture recognizer right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use following syntax:

```
let gest = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imgPressed))
```

Note, that `Selector` can accept initial type `Void` as well as `String`. Properly old-style `Selector` initialization looks like this:

```
let action: Selector = Selector("imgPressed")
```

Now you may check, that if you will try combine new style with old style you will get compilation error:

```
let action = Selector(imgPressed) // Error!
```

Funny thing is that you probably will try to resolve this error by appending bracers, and you will not have any errors after that! But this is completely useless. Look at following 3 lines of code, they are equivalent

```
let action = Selector(imgPressed())
let action = Selector(Void())
let action = Selector()
```

exept one thing - in first line you called `imgPressed()` function, returned `Void`, by your hands. Thats it =)

Answer (score 2):

Change your gesture line like following **if swift 2.0 or less**

```
let gest=UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("imgPressed"));
```

**if you are using swift 2.2 or greater than that**

```
let gest=UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imgPressed));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Well,i changed the ** Selector(imgPressed()) ** to **#selector(imgPressed)**. The issue with method calling immediately is resolved but now the method is not getting called when i tap on the image

Comment: @koushikv make sure that `userInteractionEnabled` property in your `UIImageView` is set to `true`. Add `thalaImg.userInteractionEnabled = true`  in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: You need to set the userInterActionEnabled to true